# making a combo box editable

Tags: c#, combobox

I want make the combo box editable in c# that should accept input from keyboard and from the drop-down and I want to append the text that is entered to the drop-down list.

Answer (score 13):

You need to:

1) Set the AutoCompleteMode property to AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend

2) Set the AutoCompleteSource property to AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource

3) Set the AutoCompleteCustomSource property to an AutoCompleteStringCollection of your possible matches.

Comment: Nice but can you plz elobrate the answer 
means if i use a editable combobox how can i store the new value in a database so i can retrive the same for the next time

Comment: @KiranSolkar that is outside the scope of this particular question. Please open a new question.