# How to Create combo box to auto fill while user type the spellings inside the combo Box in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` in my Windows Form that I can fill with data from a database. However, I can't fill the ComboBox when the user types letters inside it.

As an example, when the user types the letter "R" inside the ComboBox, it drops down and shows all the possible values with the letter "R".

How can I autofill the `ComboBox` when the user types something inside it?

Comment: Refer **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805638/making-a-combo-box-editable)** one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Set [`yourComboBox.AutoCompleteSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletesource.aspx) to `AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;` (if your `yourComboBox.Items` was already filled from the database)
2. Set [`yourComboBox.AutoCompleteMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletemode.aspx) to `SuggestAppend`

Comment: Thankz friend it's help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You would have to tie in with the KeyUp event on the comboBox, and, using comboBox.Text, filter the comboBox.Items collection to only show containing typed characters. You would also need to force the comboBox window to dropdown as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you:

```
private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    char ch = e.KeyChar;
    string strToFind;

    // if first char
    if (lastChar == 0)
        strToFind = ch.ToString();
    else
        strToFind = lastChar.ToString() + ch;

    // set first char
    lastChar = ch;

    // find first item that exactly like strToFind
    int idx = comboBox1.FindStringExact(strToFind);

    // if not found, find first item that start with strToFind
    if (idx == -1) idx = comboBox1.FindString(strToFind);

    if (idx == -1) return;

    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = idx;

    e.Handled = true;
}

void comboBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // remove last char before select new item
    lastChar = (char) 0;
}
```

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/csharpgeneral/thread/c02166d7-ebe7-4385-8beb-06ac10fa677a)